# Integrating $\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} dz e^{-m\sqrt{z^2+r^2}}\frac{1}{(z^2 + r^2)^{3/2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to solve the integral

$$
F(mr)=\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} dz e^{-m\sqrt{z^2+r^2}}\frac{1}{(z^2 + r^2)^{(3/2)}} \quad  (1)
$$

I have tried starting from the integral:

$$
\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} dz e^{-m\sqrt{z^2+r^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2 + r^2}}=2   K_0(mr) 
$$
where $K_0(z)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind of order $0$.

By taking derivatives of Eq. (1) with respect to $m$, I get

$$
\frac{\partial^2F(mr)}{\partial m^2}= 2K_0(mr)
$$

Therefore, in principle, by integrating $2K_0(mr)$ twice, I should be able to get $F(mr)$.

The problem is that, integrating $K_0(mr)$ once yields (according to Mathematica)
$$
\frac{\pi m}{2}(K_0(mr) L_{-1}(mr) + K_1(mr) L_0(mr)
$$
where $L_n(mr)$ is the Modified Struve function of order $n$.

Consequently, I can't really integrate this again.

Am I going wrong somewhere? Or is there another better method?

Thanks!

Andrés.

Comment: For integrals of this type, a countour approach might be helpful.  Similiar integrals come up in the computation of inverse fourier transforms, a similiar approach might work for you as follows here: http://residuetheorem.com/2013/04/23/inverse-laplace-transform-iv/

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for contour integration, you need to calculate the residue at $z=ir$

Answer (score 1):

By parity the given integral equals
$$ 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{(z^2+r^2)^{3/2}\exp(m\sqrt{z^2+r^2})}\stackrel{z\mapsto r\sinh u}{=}\frac{2}{r^2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{\cosh^3(u)\exp(mr\cosh u)} $$
or, by setting $u=\text{arccosh}(v)$,
$$ \frac{2}{r^2}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dv}{v^3\sqrt{v^2-1}}e^{-mrv}\,dv =\frac{2}{r^2 e^{mr}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-mrt}dt}{(t+1)^3 \sqrt{t(t+2)}}$$
where the last integral tends to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ when $mr\to 0^+$ and is close to $\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{13+4mr}}$ when $mr\to +\infty$, by approximating$^{(*)}$ $\frac{1}{(t+1)^3\sqrt{t+2}}$ with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{-13t/4}$. I believe there is no simple representation in terms of standard hypergeometric functions.

<sup>$(*)$ The Laplace method is the standard technique for deriving the asymptotic behaviour of $K_0$ and similar functions.</sup>